# Wordpress - WP Query : meta_query relation ignored

Tags: wordpress, arguments, meta-query

I need help with a WP_Query. I use the meta query argument using the OR and AND relations, but this argument seems to be ignored in the result of the query.

Here is my code :

```
$args = array(
    'orderby'           => 'date',
    'order'             => 'DESC',
    'post_type'         => 'my_custome_post_type',
    'posts_per_page'    => 1,
    'meta_query'        => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
                'relation' => 'AND',
                array( 'author'     => $contact_id ),
                array( 'meta_key'   => 'my_meta', 'meta_value' => $user_id )
            ),
            array(
                'relation' => 'AND',
                array( 'author'     =>  $user_id ),
                array( 'meta_key'   => 'my_meta', 'meta_value' => $contact_id )  
            )
    )
);

$query = new \WP_Query( $args );
$response = $query->posts;
```

I already tried to add this argument like suggested in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38101511/why-wordpress-ignores-meta-query-conditions):

```
'suppress_filters'     => false,
'is_your_custom_query' => true, // your custom flag
```

Even if I remplace the value of `$user_id` and `$contact_id` directly in the query with any number, the query still return the same result. I don't understand why it's not working.

Comment: Can you please elaborate the question with what you want to achieve, and what results you're currently getting. That will help to understand the scenario.

Comment: I want to get the last post in the post who have either : 1) The same author id than `$user_id` and the post_meta 'meta_value' equal as `$contact_id` 2) Or The same author id than `$contact_id` and the post_meta 'meta_value' equal as `$user_id`

Comment: The logic looks fine to me.. Did you try fixing the typing errors, 'my_custom_post_type"
new \WP_Query
or any other if present??

Comment: I think it's a simple as changing `meta_key` to `key` and `meta_value` to `value`. This has tripped me up a couple of times as well. Basically when using the array syntax for a meta_query, you drop the `meta_` prefix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for your help !

As suggested by **dafoxuk**, I have to remplace `meta_key` by `key` and `meta_value` by `value`. I also had to add `'compare' => 'LIKE'`.

But event in this case it wasn't working. I also had to stock the `author_id` in a `post_meta`, and change the `array( 'author'=> $contact_id )` condition by :

```
array( 'key '   => 'meta_author_id', 'value' => $user_id, 'compare' => 'LIKE' )
```

So the final `$args` array look like this :

```
 $args = array(
            'orderby'           => 'date',
            'order'             => 'DESC',
            'post_type'         => 'my_custome_post_type',
            'posts_per_page'    => 1,
            'meta_query'        => array(
                'relation' => 'OR',
                    array(
                        'relation' => 'AND',
                            array( 'key '   => 'meta_author_id', 'value' => $user_id, 'compare' => 'LIKE' )
                            array( 'key '   => 'my_meta', 'value' => $user_id, 'compare' => 'LIKE '
                   array(
                        'relation' => 'AND',
                            array( 'key '   => 'meta_author_id', 'value' => $user_id, 'compare' => 'LIKE' )
                            array( 'key '   => 'my_meta', 'value' => $contact_id, 'compare' => 'LIKE' )
                    )
        );
```